# New to PL/SQL can someone assist w a simple expression

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have a `PL/SQL` Expression which displays a page item's value. It's very simple:

`:P240_STREET_NAME`

So this would return, for example, `666 Fifth Avenue`

I want it to return more items, for example

```
2 BR / 1 BA on 666 Fifth Avenue
```

The item for `2 BR` is `P253_BEDROOMS` and the item that would be `1 BA` is `P240_BATHROOMS`

How would I write this expression? I'm still learning so please go easy on me :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I understand what you are asking.  You've got a page with multiple items.  Presumably 3 text boxes.  The values of those items will automatically be displayed in those items.  Unless, say, the items are hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this expression

```
  :P253_BEDROOMS || '/' || :P240_BATHROOMS || ' on ' || :P240_STREET_NAME
```

Comment: This worked! I had to create an item called '240_BEDROOMS' that ran this SQL query:`SELECT BEDROOMS_ID FROM UNITS WHERE UNIT_ID = :P240_UNIT_ID` -- is that necessary (to create the other item) or is there a way to do this right from the PL/SQL Expression itself? I guess ultimately I am thinking about speed. Do you think it makes a difference?

Comment: If appending the result of that query to the answer I've given then you can do it without creating another item: `SELECT BEDROOMS_ID  ||  :P253_BEDROOMS || '/' || :P240_BATHROOMS || ' on ' || :P240_STREET_NAME FROM UNITS WHERE UNIT_ID = :P240_UNIT_ID`. Change your source type from "PL/SQL Expression" to "SQL query"

Comment: The problem I am having is the _ID fields are just reference numbers (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5). So for example BEDROOMS_ID is a number column (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) with an associated varchar 2 column called just BEDROOMS with a name for each of those IDs (i.e. 1 = 1 BR, 2 = 2 BR). When I pull in the BEDROOMS_ID, i get the number ("1") and not the name ("1 BR"). How do I pull the name varchar 2 column?

Comment: use bedroom_name column instead of BEDROOMS_ID column in your query